# Performance of memory function depends on type of target object allocation?

Tags: c++, memory, performance-testing

When we measured the performance of the C++ standard memcpy function (Visual Studio 2015) we observed a difference depending on whether the objects to be copied from/to had been allocated globally (outside the main() function) or on the heap. The performance appears to be better for global objects. Any explanation for that?

For performance testing I used the chrono library.

My test function (nTest = 5, nOp = 100.000, mySourceArray and myDestArray are arrays of char, arraySize = 1.000.000):

```
void std_memcpy_aligned(std::string testDescr, int nTest, int nOp, char mySourceArray[], char myDestArray[],const int arraySize)
    {
        std::cout << "Performance test: " << testDescr << '\n' << "number of operations/run: " << nOp << '\n';

        for (int i = 0; i < nTest; ++i) {
            //Measure performance
            auto begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); //start time
            for (int ii = 0; ii < nOp; ++ii) {
                memcpy(myDestArray, mySourceArray, arraySize);//aligned source and aligned target address
            }
            auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); //end time
            std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - begin).count() << "ms" << '\n';
        }
    }
```

The difference between tests using global objects vs. objects on the heap was about 5%.

> In detail: n=10 test runs, "heap" test: 8513 ms +/- 114 ms (mean +/-
>   sd), "global" test: 8113 ms +/- 52 ms (mean +/- sd), result is highly
>   statistically significant

Comment: I would not dare commenting on the speed of code that I haven't run myself, with no information other than "appears to be better". There are millions of things that could make a difference, and millions of things that could make you measure something entirely different than you think you are measuring.

Comment: Better by how much ? Can you share the code ? How many times did you measure ?